# playwright can't import from absolute path

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I am writing playwright tests for a meteor react + nodejs app. My test resides in `/tests/e2e` I have to import some helpers in tests to prepare data, those helpers are using absolute imports

eg
`import {CommentsModal} from "/imports/db/modals"`

Playwright give me error when I run test

`Error: Cannot find module /imports/db/modals`

same helper imported in code works fine.

for context:
I don't have typescript, not configuring modules path.